# To check whether the email exists in database using Jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code. 
The GetByuserEmail takes the input email and checks with the database.If exists it returns the email.In checkmail() method the GetByUserEmail method is called and if the email exists then it should have returned true. Please check where might have gone wrong.

```
*public User GetByUserEmail(string email)
        {
            var users = db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == email);
            if (users.Count() > 0)
            {
                return users.First();
            }
            return null;
        }*


In regitster Controller,

*public JsonResult checkEmail(string email)
        {
            Models.User user = userRepository.GetByUserName(email);
            bool exists = (user != null);
            JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
            result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
            result.Data = new { Exist = exists };
            return result;

        }*


It returns in json format

*{"Exist":false}*
```

Comment: Have you looked in the database to verify the user exists with that email? Have you verified there is no difference between the email you're passing and the email in the database? Have you verified your application is connecting to the correct database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
Models.User user = userRepository.GetByUserName(email);
```

be

```
Models.User user = userRepository.GetByUserEmail(email);
```

?

EDIT: you are probably calling the wrong method on the first line from `checkEmail` method.

Answer (score 0):

If Alexnadru's answer doesn't work try this:

```
var users = db.Users.Where(u => u.Email.ToLower() == email.ToLower());
```

Depending on your database settings mike@email.com <> Mike@Email.Com (capitalization)